# Validate if there is a comma-delimited record PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to validate if there is a CONCILIATOR record in the PROFILE table, if it exists I send for an exception otherwise I continue the procedure.

I tried to use the INSTR function but I don't know how to perform the validation within my procedure.

```
CONTAINS := SELECT INSTR(CONCIL, ( SELECT CONCIL 
                                   FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL 
                                   WHERE CONCIL LIKE P_CONCIL 
                                   OR CONCIL = ','||P_CONCIL 
                                   OR CONCIL = P_CONCIL||',')) AS CONTAINSa  
            FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL;
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please include some sample data, and your expected results

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with details of your table structure, the data the table holds and the inputs to your procedure. You say you need to check the `PROFILE` table but then give us code that queries a completely different table; please help us to help you by giving us **ALL** of the information and not just a small snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understood the question; see comments within code.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From tb_ediext_perfil;

        ID CONCIL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 This, contains a comma
         2 No comma here at all
         3 Here they are: Scott, King and Mike
```

Code:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select id, concil
  3                  from tb_ediext_perfil
  4                 )
  5    loop
  6      if instr(cur_r.concil, ',') > 0 then
  7         -- CONCIL contains comma; send it for exception (though,
  8         -- I don't know what it actually means)
  9         dbms_output.put_line('send for exception: ' || cur_r.concil);
 10         null;
 11      else
 12         -- continue the procedure
 13         dbms_output.put_line('continue: ' || cur_r.concil);
 14         null;
 15      end if;
 16    end loop;
 17  end;
 18  /
send for exception: This, contains a comma
continue: No comma here at all
send for exception: Here they are: Scott, King and Mike

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that it sends the exception when there is a comma in the field, but the field can contain more than one record without a comma and I would like to validate that the record exists and not the comma. Example:
               `CONCIL
CONCILIA,NEXXERA,EQUALS`
And if I enter the parameter P_CONCIL = EQUALS, it checks the field if it contains EQUALS and sends it to the exception.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, not a problem: modify line #6 to `if instr(cur_r.concil, p_concil) > 0`

Comment: Wow! What a lack of attention on my part! It worked! Thanks @Littlefoot

Answer (score 0):

```
CONTAINS :=  SELECT INSTR(CONCIL, ( SELECT CONCIL FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL WHERE CONCIL LIKE P_CONCIL OR CONCIL = ','||P_CONCIL OR CONCIL = P_CONCIL||',')) AS CONTAINSa  
FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL
```

Is not valid in Oracle. You need to use the `INTO` clause to get data into your variable:

```
SELECT INSTR(CONCIL, (SELECT CONCIL
                        FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL
                        WHERE CONCIL LIKE P_CONCIL OR 
                              CONCIL = ','||P_CONCIL OR CONCIL = P_CONCIL||',')) AS CONTAINSa  
  INTO CONTAINS
  FROM TB_EDIEXT_PERFIL
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c9dbd230266c3e1d7b4ec4ac7a5caf3)

Comment: That will become problematic if the sub-query ever returns more than one row.

Comment: @Stilgar: agreed, but trying to show OP how to handle the case they seemed to be interested in. One question at a time, one question at a time... :-)

Comment: The logic of your code serves me partially, the problem is that it can return more than one line and as @Stilgar commented, this can be a problem ... How to solve?

Comment: I think two options for this.  Either change CONTAINS into a COLLECTION then check CONTAINS.COUNT() or wrap that query in a EXCEPTION block and trap the too-many-rows exception.  Either option should already be explained on this site or you can post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  contains BOOLEAN;
  v_concil PROFILE.CONCIL%TYPE;
  p_concil PROFILE.CONCIL%TYPE := 'some_value';
BEGIN
  SELECT CONCIL
  INTO   v_concil
  FROM   PROFILE;

  contains := ','||v_concil||',' LIKE '%,'||p_concil||',%';
  IF contains THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'contains' );
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'not contains' );
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    contains := FALSE;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'not contains' );
END;
/
```

So for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE profile ( concil VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO profile ( concil ) VALUES ( 'other_value,some_value' );
```

This outputs:

> ```
> contains
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e97768d61a6550bfb2287cbca30b739)*